# Passing argument/key pair to vscode Python debugger separated with an equal sign

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, fb-hydra

For management of my config files, I'm using [Hydra](https://hydra.cc) which requires passing additional arguments using a plus and then an equal sign between the argument and its value, e.g.

```
python evaluate.py '+model_path="logs/fc/version_1/checkpoints/epoch=1-step=2.ckpt"'
```

Above I'm also using quotes to escape the equal signs in the value.

I want to pass this in vscode to `launch.json` to the `args` field; however, I don't know how to do it properly because typically the argument and value parts are separated by a space and not an equal sign as for Hydra. So the following doesn't work:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "args" : ["+model_path", "logs/fc/version_1/checkpoints/epoch=1-step=2.ckpt"]
    }
  ]
}
```

How should I change `args` to get it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant solution but it works if we pass everything as a single argument (no comma inbetween) like this:

`"args" : ["+model_path='logs/fc/version_7/checkpoints/epoch=19-step=3700.ckpt'"]`

Answer (score 0):

> If you need to pass arguments to the Python interpreter, you can use the `pythonArgs` property.

Use the following syntax:

```
"pythonArgs": ["<arg 1>", "<arg 2>",...]
```

If you pass paired arguments with `args`:

```
"args" : ["--port", "1593"]
```

There are more details on **launch.json** configuration [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_set-configuration-options).

Comment: This assumes that the arguments and values are separated by a space. That is not the case for Hydra; there is an equal sign inbetween. So this doesn't work.